# Precision of computations done by Plot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, bugs, numerics

I get a nice plot, but also a FindRoot::precw: error when I try to plot the results of a function that invokes `FindRoot`. I assume the problem originates in how `Plot` passes the arguments to the function. Here is a simple notebook that shows this behavior:

```
eqn = 5*x + 0.1000000000000000000000 + s == 0
(* 0.100000000000000000000 + s + 5 x == 0 *)

Precision[eqn]
(* 21. *)

g[b_] :=  
      FindRoot[{eqn /. s -> b}, {{x, -13000}}, 
        MaxIterations -> 1000,  WorkingPrecision -> 20]

g[-1]
(* {x -> 0.18000000000000000000} *)

g[100]
(* {x -> -20.020000000000000000} *)

Plot[x /. g[s], {s, -10, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

> FindRoot::precw: The precision of the argument function ({-9.89959+5 x==0}) is less than WorkingPrecision (20.`). >>

I tried with and without the `WorkingPrecision` option in the plot, and also by wrapping the ranges with a set precision like:

```
Plot[x/. g[s], {s, SetPrecision[-10, 20], SetPrecision[-10, 20}}]
```

which looks strange and does not work as well...

To be clear, the generated plot looks nice, but the errors are still annoying.

Comment: I think `Plot` is testing the function by plugging in a machine precision value (like ``-9.99959142857143` ``, but also the exact integer `10`).

Comment: Even if I lower the working precision to 9 or even to 1, the error appears...

Comment: That's because `MachinePrecision` is considered less than any arbitrary precision by `FindRoot`.  You could use `Quiet` to ignore the warning.  (It's not an error.)  Or you could use `SetPrecision` inside `g`, but I would be less happy with that in some situations.

Comment: I think I can live with the `Quiet` solution, even though I think it is somewhat inconvenient. But I'm relieved that I should not worry too much about this warning.

Comment: One can see why they analyze/test the function with machine numbers, because they're faster.  If there is an option to turn this off, it's bound to be more work than `Quiet@Plot[..]` or even `Quiet[Plot[..], FindRoot::precw]`, which would let real numerical errors be reported.

Comment: If I remove `WorkingPrecision -> 20` in `g[b_] `as well as in the `Plot`I do not get the error and the plot is the same.

Comment: In my real notebook I wanted to use a certain `WorkingPrecision` because the plot had some numerical features. Of course in this minimal example, it works without

Answer (score 3):

#### Update

I reported this issue to Wolfram tech support and received a reply. I quote the relevant portions thereof.

> I have confirmed the issue you are experiencing with the FindRoot::precw and FindRoot::nlnum errors being printed when they shouldn't be. I spent a fair amount of time digging into this, and it seems the underlying reason is that the precision of [the variable] is sometimes not being set.
>
> For some reason, Precision is kept at MachinePrecision for certain values of [the variable]. This is what is triggering the error message. I have not been able to isolate why this is occurring.

I am marking the question with the tag [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs).