# How can I remove the FindRoot error from my calculations?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, precision-and-accuracy

If you run my calculations given below

```
x[r_] = Integrate[1/(1 - 1/r - (r/4)^2), r] // Normal

Sol = NSolve[16 - 16 x + x^3 == 0, x, WorkingPrecision -> 100];
R1 = First[Sort[x /. Sol, Smaller]]
R2 = Sort[x /. Sol, Smaller][[2]]
R3 = Sort[x /. Sol, Smaller][[3]]

V = Simplify[(1 -a/r-b*r^2)*((l*(1 + l))/r^2 + (a/r^2 - 2*b*r)/r) /. {a -> 1, 
b -> 1/16} /. l -> 1];
ndvar = -16 ((Log[r - R1] R1)/(-16 + 3 R1^2) + (
Log[r - R2] R2)/(-16 + 3 R2^2) + (Log[R3 - r] R3)/(-16 + 3 R3^2));

fV[z_?NumericQ] :=If[Abs[z] <= 400,Re[V /. FindRoot[ndvar == z, {r,11/10`100}, 
AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, MaxIterations -> 10000,PrecisionGoal -> 100, 
WorkingPrecision -> 100]], 0];

Plot[fV[x], {x, -50, 50}, PlotRange -> All,AxesLabel -> {"v - u", "V"},
  ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

you will find a FindRoot error at the end which I could not remove it by using help center. How can I remove it? I will be thankful if someone help.

Comment: Do you want to fix the error or suppress the message ? Off[General::precw] will suppress it.

Comment: Yeah, in this case the error is actually only a warning. It can suppressed without worries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Henrik Schumacher's answer gets you half way there. The other half of the problem is that the [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) iterator is machine precision.  You can correct this by expressly applying [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html):

```
Plot[fV[SetPrecision[x, 100]], {x, -50, 50}
 , PlotRange -> All
 , AxesLabel -> {"v - u", "V"}
 , ImageSize -> Large
 , LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}
]
```

This is needed to work around a bug: [Precision of computations done by Plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133933/121)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have a suggestion to remove errors at the end of `sol = NDSolveValue[{-4*D[S[u, v], u, v] == 
     fV[v - u]*S[u, v], 
    S[u, 0] == Exp[-(-vc)^2/(2*sigma^2)], 
    S[0, v] == Exp[-(v - vc)^2/(2*sigma^2)]} /. {vc -> 10, 
    sigma -> 3}, S, {u, 120, 210}, {v, 120, 210}, MaxStepSize -> 1]`. This equation comes after the code given in my question.

Comment: Oh my. I forgot about that... (+1)

Comment: @Henrik -- You also have my +1 of course.  Any ideas re: the comment above?

Comment: @Mehrab For further numerical computstions, it might be worthwhile to redefine  `fV` as follows: `fV[z0_?NumericQ] := With[{z = SetPrecision[z0, prec + 1]},
   If[Abs[z] <= 400,
    Re[V /. FindRoot[
       ndvar == z, {r, 11/10},
       MaxIterations -> 10000,
       WorkingPrecision -> prec
       ]
     ],
    0
    ]
   ];`. But also not that it is rather pointless use such high (working-)precision functions within  `NDSolve`: You will usually only obtain a few digits precision for the solution, in particular with the humongous step sizes.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks a lot, but what is `prec`?

Comment: Oh sorry. Just set it to `100`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Ok it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

`NSolve` loses a bit of precision (less than a digit). Grant it some extra digits with

```
Sol = NSolve[16 - 16 x + x^3 == 0, x, WorkingPrecision -> 110];
```

and it should wotk fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you restrict your final parameterrange to `-40<x<40` you can get an easy  straightforward solution (without setting Precsision)

```
sol[z_?NumericQ] :=V /.  NSolve[{ndvar == z, R2 < r < R3}, r, Reals][[1]]
Plot[sol[x], {x, -40, 40}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]